# Update Datatables column searching dropdownbox after ajax load

Tags: datatables

I added a filtering function with Individual column searching (https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) to my datatable which is working fine.
This table also has a button to reload table data. The button triggers code like:

```
table.ajax.url("foo").load();
```

It updates table data correctly. Now, I want to update searching dropdown box with new column data. I want to empty dropdown box something like select.empty() then fill the box, but not sure how. I think this update process should be written in "rowCallback".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

To rebuild the drop-downs after each ajax call, here is one approach:

1. Instead of using the DataTables `ajax` option, you can fetch the data using a jQuery ajax call, outside of DataTables.
2. Use the jQuery `done` function populate the table, and re-build the drop-downs after each ajax call.

This approach ensures that the ajax data has been fetched before any additional processing takes place.

**Walkthrough**

Assume we have a button like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="fetchData();">Reload Data</button>
```

And a HTML table like this:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>  <!-- you may need more footer cells in your table -->
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Here is the related `fetchData` function, which clears all existing data, then re-populates the table with the newly fetched data:

```
function fetchData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: [your url goes here],  // your URL here
    context: document.body
  }).done(function( data ) {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.clear();
    table.rows.add(data);
    buildSelectLists();
    table.draw();
  });
}
```

The function to rebuild the select lists is identical to the logic from the DataTables example solution:

```
function buildSelectLists() {
  
  $('#example').DataTable().columns().every(function() {
    var column = this;

    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
      .on('change', function() {

        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );
        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
    });
  });
}
```

Finally, the DataTable is defined in a "document ready" function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable({
    // your options here - but no need for the ajax or data options
    "initComplete": function() {
      fetchData(); // make sure the table contains data, when it is created
    }
  });

});
```

---

Alternatively:

You can achieve a similar result by using the DataTables `ajax` option which makes use of a function:

Example (taken from the [documentation here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    callback(
      JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('dataTablesData') )
    );
  }
} );
```

I think in this case, it is a bit cleaner to keep the `ajax` call in its own separate function.

Comment: Your solusion worked pefectly! Thanks a lot!